# Could besieged medieval cities develop a micro-economy during wars to endure the siege for long time?

Tags: war, economy, siege

During the medieval age, one of the main reasons that pushed besieged cities to capitulate was the exhaustion of provisions (foods,water,drugs...) that maintain the every-day life of the city population.

I wonder to what extent could a city generate its own resources by harnessing the little bit of available room and creating farms, small factories and recycling, thus avoiding famine, plague and acquiring what could spare souls...

I konow that someones may argue that there is not enough space to create farms or factories but cities like Byzantium or Cairo were huge and have enough room for that.

Are there any known cities that have been through such an experience, enduring sieges, or was the only hope to smuggle provisions through the enemy lines?

Comment: depends on the city, but take Antioch for example,  its size is approximately 1100 acres.  Its population was anywhere between 100k and 400k.  Assuming the entire city was nothing but fields for planting, you would have .01 acres per person.  A person needs at min .5 acres of prime agriculture land to survive.  So no, even if they turned over the entire city into a farm it would not supply enough food.

Comment: This question would benefit from preliminary research.  Few cities could feed themselves in normal circumstances. When the farming population of the surrounding countryside flees within the walls it further strains supplies.

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace: I'd change "few" to "no".  It's an inescapable part of being a city, rather than a fairly dense rural area.  Even as late as WWII, Britain imported a large part of its food, and the Germans hoped to starve the British into surrendering with its naval attacks on merchant ships.

Comment: I think you're right that no cities could feed themselves, but I didn't want to argue the point.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace That would depend on the diet, on a vegan diet Britain could feed a lot more than on the current diet.

Comment: I've deleted my comment that is not germane to the historical question.  Although the question is far from settled, my understanding is that most of the population would have been on an effectively vegetarian diet to begin with, and switching to vegan would have severely restricted their caloric intake (eggs).  The question introduces a hypothesis; the burden of proof is to demonstrate the plausibility of that hypothesis.  Consensus is that the hypothesis is implausible.

Comment: I thought there were some fairly standard references on the number of calories that could be produced by a unit of land under different economic/technological constraints.  If anyone could find that, it would help to authoritatively answer this question. (The reason I commented rather than answering is that I can't recall where I read those things).

Comment: @gerrit: No, that's false. On a *vegan* diet the people would rapidly develop sever health problems from the absence of the supplements needed to remain healthy on a *vegan* diet. There's a reason the full cost of eating *vegan* is greater than eating a normal healthy diet including meat. Britain also has a large area of pasture land unsuitable for any agriculture besides livestock and dairy. Same reason why no third world countries eat *vegan* - far more expensive than otherwise.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Why would there be an absence of supplements? The overconsumption of meat already currently leads to serious health problems. And don't forget that Britain has a large area of sea, [which could be used for novel crops](https://www.thenation.com/article/archive/this-former-fisherman-is-now-farming-the-most-sustainable-food-on-earth-underwater/), either for direct consumption or a source for extracting supplements. I agree though, that a single city could never be self-sustainable, certainly not with medieval technology (*perhaps* with lab-grown food / space station technology).

Comment: For context, my point was that Britain as a whole could *perhaps* feed itself on a vegan diet (maybe vegetarian would be good enough), with todays technology.  Not a city with medieval technology.

Comment: 1) @jihedgasmi - please don't take anything I said above as critical; I'm struggling to understand the question and fit my thoughts in the space of a comment (because I don't have an answer). 2) let's halt discussion of modern day diets - I was in error to introduce the topic. Let's keep the focus on the original historical question.

Comment: don't think on walled cities as modern cities, large avenues and parks. Walls were expensive => inside-wall space was limited => inside was crowded, high pop density => no enough space to feed everybody. **BUT**, every time a city/castle took care to have wells, or was built in a place that kept a water source/river/spring/underground river accessible from inside the walls, they at least would be self-sufficient on **water**

Comment: Would a "micro-economy" not just be called "the economy"?

Comment: Before the black death, England was right at the carrying capacity of the land using medieval methods.  Peasant diets were low-meat due to this.  Eggs and diary were common because those were good ways to convert non-edible plant material into food, while pigs were used because they also were good at converting food waste and non-edible material found in forests into calories.  @Pieter Geerken's point about land unsuitable for food production is important, and it's the reason why there have been vegetarian societies, but not vegan ones.

Comment: @GorttheRobot: It is well noted that in both WW1 and WW2 the Canucks, Yanks, Kiwis and Aussies arriving in Britain were 3" - 4" taller on average than their British age peers. This is largely due to the increased availability of meat in their diets, particularly when young..

Comment: Maybe meat, maybe just better diet in general.  (My boy is has been vegetarian since birth and at 17, has never failed to be tallest in his class.)

Comment: @Gort the Robot: Part of the reason medieval British peasants didn't eat much meat is that the aristocracy largely reserved hunting for themselves, with potentially quite severe punishments for those caught poaching.

Comment: [What was the surface of cereal crop needed per head per year during-the Dark Ages](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9044/what-was-the-size-of-surface-of-a-cereal-crop-needed-per-man-per-year-during-the?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This question would have benefited some research of at least basics medieval lifestyle and economy. Drugs? There were no drugs at that time. Recycling? Everything was recycled anyways, with or without a siege. Factories? Factories did not exist at that time either. On the other hand, manufactures were exclusive to cities, so again, with or without siege...

Comment: @jamesqf Hunting was not the major source of meat in Europe in the middle ages.

Answer (score 33):

No.  Cities were simply too small physically to feed themselves.  [Constantinople](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantinople) was one of the biggest cities of its time, at 2.3 sq miles.  This works out to around 1500 acres.  To feed a single person you need, at minimum [6-8 acres of land](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9044/what-was-the-size-of-surface-of-a-cereal-crop-needed-per-man-per-year-during-the).  This means that if the entire area of the city were farmland, it would feed at best around 250 people.

Even with modern farming methods, you would need just under [1/2 acre per person](http://archive.boston.com/bostonglobe/ideas/brainiac/2013/03/how_much_land_d.html).  That still puts you at only around 3000 people.

Using extreme techniques, some people claim to be able to do as well as even [20 people per acre](https://www.smallfootprintfamily.com/how-much-land-is-needed-to-be-self-sufficient).  This requires a large investment in modern technological produces like drip irrigation, and assumes access to electricity and running water.  If we took this number, and applied it to Constantinople, we would get roughly 30,000 people fed.  (Assuming you could do it at this scale, which no one has even done in modern times.)

Constantinople had on the order of a half million people, which puts it at around 350 people per acre.  So yeah, this is just entirely unworkable even with modern techniques.

Comment: If this is the case, how could some cities survive decade long sieges? Although rare, such things did happen even in ancient times. I would guess blockade runners, smuggling in resupply once in a while when the encirclement was less than perfect (or through secret tunnels?), or maybe even sorties and raids, looting supplies and then hurrying back behind the walls before the besiegers could mobilize.

Comment: @vsz They survived for years because the sieges were incomplete. The besieging force was on land and the sieged city had a harbour, for example.

Comment: Modern industrial agriculture optimizes food production per unit of human labor, *not* food production per unit of land. Corn and wheat make up a large portion of our diet because they are amenable to mechanical harvesting. The claim that it takes 1/2 acre to feed a person is massively distorted by the inclusion of those crops. Similarly, pork is a relatively inefficient source of protein. With a different diet, a person can be fed on about 1/20 acre.

Comment: @user560822 - are you sure about that?  and what diet would allow a person to be fed on 1/20 of an acre, which is less than 50' x 50' or the size of a small house (without counting the yard?)  And regardless of that,  even if your scenario were true, according to the math, you would still not be able to feed a city the size of antioch or constantinople

Comment: @ed.hank About as sure as I can be without doing it myself (yet.) [This page](https://www.smallfootprintfamily.com/how-much-land-is-needed-to-be-self-sufficient) claims you can feed a person on less than 1000 square feet, which I'm a little skeptical of, but includes links to several examples of people feeding their families on approximately 1/20 acre per person.

Comment: @user560822 Modern techniques aren't relevant to the question.  Note that that page assumes access to electricity and running water.  *Even so*, the population density of Constantinople was 340 people per acre, so even if you accept being able to feed 20 people from an acre of land, you are *still* an order of magnitude short.  (Medieval urban population densities greatly exceeded that of modern cities)

Comment: @GorttheRobot They're relevant in that they put an upper limit on what is realistic. I commented because these techniques are *more* relevant in establishing that limit than the previously cited productivity of modern industrial farming. In my grandfather's day, "bio-intensive organic farming" was just called "farming." (Or a "victory garden.")

Comment: @user560822 Your view on corn and wheat is ridiculous. They were the base of the agricultural production and the main staple food in their respective civilizations well before industrial agriculture.

Comment: @Greg That doesn't contradict my point. Since around 1940, industrialization has [dramatically increased](https://ourworldindata.org/crop-yields) the availability of corn and grain. That productivity supports a larger population, but the growth in productivity has significantly outpaced the growth in population. In the US, the per capita availability of corn has [more than doubled](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2016/12/13/whats-on-your-table-how-americas-diet-has-changed-over-the-decades/) just since 1970. A different diet would require more labor, but less land.

Comment: Medieval societies had no way to produce fertilization via nitrogen fixing.  That is the core reason for that great increase of availability.

Comment: @user560822 One of the links is "[Growing Power](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgLo0xUhs5U) – On a 2-acre urban lot in Milwaukee, Will Allen grows over a million pounds of food every year, including thousands of fish, and a livestock inventory of chickens, goats, and bees." Can you give me a time stamp of where it says in the YouTube video that they grow a million pounds of food? That website is trying to sell books.

Comment: BTW, when I copy and pasted that quote, I got "Original article at: https://www.smallfootprintfamily.com/how-much-land-is-needed-to-be-self-sufficient#ixzz6DxxA8BfH
© 2018 Small Footprint Family™ | All rights reserved. NOTHING ON THIS SITE MAY BE REPUBLISHED OR REPRINTED WITHOUT WRITTEN PERMISSION OF THE AUTHOR. Please use social sharing buttons to share on Facebook, Pinterest, etc." So I guess I'm violating those conditions by posting the quote here, but I think it's covered by Fair Use, and the fact that the website claims that discussing its claims is prohibited is hardly a good sign.

Comment: Also, I looked up marijuana yields, and found this: [https://www.cannabisbusinesstimes.com/article/measuring-yield/ ](Yield per square foot ranged among research participants from 60g/sq. ft. or more to less than 20g/sq. ft.) Over two acres, that corresponds to 11523 pounds. That appears to be per harvest, so if there are 7 harvests/year, that's 80661 lbs/year. This is with grow lights and fossil fuel based fertilizers. Hardly sustainable. And it's less than a tenth of what the website claims.

Comment: @vsz Some cities had large stockpiles of food.

Comment: @user560822 - did you even read the link you posted,  it shows that it requires basically 2 acres to feed a family of 4, see the handy infographic at the bottom.  And again this is assuming modern techniques.  Also in both mine and Gorts calculations we assume the entire city is a farm and that land is productive,  when in reality at most 50-60% that space could be used for farming,  i mean people need to live somewhere right, they need roads, etc...  So still the answer is a resounding NO a city could not self-sustain itself in a siege.  Also corn did not exist in medieval europe.

Comment: Yes, you can grow a lot of food in a small area if you use hydroponic grow lights.  That's entirely irrelevant to a medieval city.  Try growing 60g/sq ft of marijuana in an open field with no electricity, no fertilization except manure, and only locally diverted water sources.  It ain't gonna work.

Answer (score 6):

As answered in comments and by Gort, there is zero chance of this happening by growing crops. It's not just the space that's insufficient, it's the complete and utter lack of soil.

The [one workaround](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Suiyang) involves 2 things:

- Exploitation of *all* available food sources.
- Drastic reduction of population.

Comment: I'm not sure if reducing population from 30,000 to 400 by cannibalism and *then* surrendering counts as a workaround...

Comment: @gerrit: There is the further problem that the *food source* vastly outnumbers the *garrison* determined to *consume* said food source, and the obvious *end-game* starkly follows Niemöller's Law: "*First they came for the **really** fat people, and I did not speak out — because I was not a **really** fat person. Then they came for the modestly fat people, and I did not speak out because I was not modestly fat. Then they came for the average-weight people, and I did not speak out because I was merely thin. ....*"

Comment: At the siege of Alesia they considered cannibalism, luckily in the end they only kicked out all of the citizens out of the city and left them to starve in no-mans land.

Comment: Drastically reducing your population is defeating the purpose of the whole siege business. You go behind the walls to protect yourself. And you stay there to fight back. It is like committing mass suicide on the battlefield to prevent a battle.

Comment: @Greg Was the Monty Python reference intentional?

Comment: @Greg If "yourself" is the king, and you are concerned only with protecting yourself and not your subjects, then reducing the population can be effective strategy. Or if you're being attacked by Bolton and everyone's going to be skinned alive anyway, then it is rational to at least save some people.

Answer (score 5):

If people could grow enough food in cities, then they wouldn't have farms, they would just have cities.

Even modern farms would not be able to supply enough food, and they are far from self-sufficient. They are heavily dependent on water and fossil fuels.

And your title is a bit misleading; "economy" refers to the management of resources, not its production (although production of resources is a factor in economies). One can't stop a population from starving just by passing money around.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence